# Apply Pandas Styler to MultiIndex list

Tags: css, python-3.x, pandas, multi-index, pandas-styles

I have a multi-index pivot table that I am making from a dataframe as shown below:

`pivot_summary = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Team', 'Associate Name'], columns=['Date'], values=['Call Transfers'], aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0, margins=True, margins_name='Grand Total')`

I then have a function called "SubTotals" which calculates the Totals for each Team and adds them to level 1 in the multi-index.

```
def SubTotals(df):
    '''
    The purpose of this function is to add sub-totals to each individual team 
    '''
    #create a dataframe with the totals of each team
    sub_totals = df.sum(level=0)
    #create variable that stores string of team # + 'Total'
    sub_totals_str = sub_totals.index.str[:] + ' Total'
    
    #add the subtotals for each team to the main dataframe
    final_df = df.append(sub_totals.assign(Team=sub_totals_str).set_index('Team', append=True)).sort_index()
    
    #drop the duplicate "Grand-Total" row at the bottom
    final_df.drop(final_df.tail(1).index, inplace=True)
    
    #create string variables of both index(Multi-level index) to zip into tuples
    index_level_0 = sub_totals.index.tolist()
    index_level_1 = sub_totals_str.tolist()
    
    #remove duplicate "Grand Total" from second index
    index_level_1[-1] = ''     
    
    #zip index to pass through formatting function
    team_totals_index = list(zip(index_level_0,index_level_1))
    
    return final_df, team_totals_index
```

So far everything is good, I get the subtotals for each team exactly how I want. Where I am stuck is that I want to highlight all the rows that are in the "teams_totals_index" variable.  I am trying to create a function "highlight_rows" that takes the list of multi-index as parameter and highlights if there is a match. I have seen many examples where lambda is used instead and it has served me as a crude check, for example:
`final_df.style.apply(lambda x: ['background: lightgreen' if x.name==('Grand Total','') else '' for i in x], axis=1)`

produces the result I am looking for, it highlights the Multi-Index ('Grand Total', '') row entirely however I also want to highlight all the other teams. I do not want to hard-code each index into a lambda function since the amount of teams is dynamic.

I have tried to use the lambda function is an example to create my own but I am having no success. below is what I have attempted.

```
def highlight_rows(x, index_list):
    '''
    highlight the maximum Totals of each team and Grand Total.
    '''
    df_styler = x.copy()
    
    b_color = 'background: lightgreen'
    
    for index_0, index_1 in index_list:
        df_styler.loc[index_0, index_1] = b_color
        
    return df_styler
```

I then try to apply `final_df.style.apply(highlight_rows, index_list=team_totals_index, axis=1)`

but I get a ValueError: Length Mismatch, expected value 32, new axis has 22 elements

I have also tried:

```
def highlight_rows(x, index_list):
    '''
    highlight the maximum Totals of each team and Grand Total.
    '''
    
      
    for index_0, index_1 in index_list:
        if x.name== (index_0, index_1):
            return ['background: lightgreen']
        else:
            return ''
```

But I also receive the same ValueError: Length Mismatch, expected value 1 element, new value has 22 elements.

Essentially I want to iterate over my list 'total_teams_index' which contains the multi-level index that I want to highlight. Any insight on how I could accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't seem to structure this as a function and make it work, I have found a workable solution without having to hard-code each index pair. I am using method chains to build up the style piece-wise as suggested by the documentation.

```
final_df.style.\
    apply(lambda x: ['background-color: #FF9900'
                     if x.name in team_totals_index else 'background-color:#FFCC99' for i in x], axis=1).\
    apply(lambda x: ['font-weight: bold' if x.name in team_totals_index else '' for i in x], axis=1).\
    apply(lambda x: ['border-top-style:solid' if x.name in team_totals_index else '' for i in x], axis=1).\
    apply(lambda x: ['border-bottom-style:solid' if x.name in team_totals_index else '' for i in x], axis=1)
```

I personally don't like the repetitive use of the same loop but it serves my purpose and styles everything exactly as needed. The key to getting all this to work was `if x.name in [list containing index pairs]` instead of trying to iterate over each index pair as shown in my examples above. I hope this may help anyone that comes across and can still potentially chime in on a less verbose/function friendly way of structuring this.